# Misalignment in Top Answerers

Tags: bug, design

Badge count is causing misalignment in many of the [Top `tag` Answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css3/topusers) lists.

---

[image]

Comment: Should they *really* be aligned though? They're two different lists.

Comment: Easy fix: just suspend the mod ...

Comment: It will soon be necessary to start truncating badge counts like we do for reputation—e.g., 1k. Feels like this has been reported and suggested before.

Comment: @CodyGray Looked for one, didn't find. If you know where, show me and I just delete this and pay my respect for the other

Comment: The problem here is that the number of badges can go to two lines - which is happening for BoltClock and is pushing the rest of the list down.

Comment: @Oded Yes, I understand where it comes from, and it happens at many of these lists, but for me, when the whole site breathes _pro's_, this kind of doesn't

Comment: Look for questions mentioning Jon Skeet; you'll find lots of alignment "bugs"...

Comment: @Jeeter Could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: @LGSon [inspired by this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775) (fyi i didn't *actually* downvote)

Comment: @Jeeter Will definitely draw freehand next time :)